# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string when using cast

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why do I get this error when using `cast` with date and time? Before its working but now its not working. What do I need to change?

This is the select statement:

```
SELECT
      [Order_Payments].[order_id] as 'Order No.'
      , try_convert(numeric(38,2),order_vat) as 'VAT value'
      , try_convert(numeric(38,2),vat_orders.[total_amount]) as 'Total After VAT'
      , [Order_Payments].cash as 'Cash'
      , Order_Payments.mada as 'Mada'
      , Order_Payments.visa as 'Visa'
      , vat_orders.order_date AS 'Order Date'
      , cast(vat_orders.order_date as time) as [time]
      , Customers.CustName as 'Clinic'
      , patients.patient_name as 'Patient Name'       
  FROM [Order_Payments]
  INNER JOIN vat_orders ON [Order_Payments].order_id = vat_orders.ORDER_ID
  INNER JOIN Customers ON [Order_Payments].custid = Customers.CustId
  INNER JOIN Patients ON [Order_Payments].patient_no = patients.patient_no
  WHERE CAST(vat_orders.order_date AS time) BETWEEN '00:00:09' AND '23:59:80'
  AND CAST(vat_orders.order_date AS date) BETWEEN '2021-05-01' AND '2021-05-05'
  AND order_payments.custid = 271
  ORDER BY Order_Payments.custid, Order_Payments.order_id
```

The error in the `cast` in `where` clause. Please your help.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] including the sample data which is causing the problem. According to the error you are storing datetime values as a string (which is a very bad design decision), and you now have some incorrect data in there which you have to find. Also please post the exact error verbatim.

Comment: What is `23:59:80`?

Comment: You're already using try_convert(numeric(38,2),...).  Why not use try_convert(time,...)   it will return an error if the conversion fails.

Comment: @MartinSmith I could have looked at that 100 times and not register the :80

Comment: I must admit, what is `CAST(vat_orders.order_date AS time) BETWEEN '00:00:09' AND '23:59:80'` trying to achieve anyway? What was `80` meant to mean? It seems like you're trying to include the *entire* day anyway, so why not just `AND order_date >= '20210501' AND order_date < '20210506'`? [Casting to a date *is* SARGable, but it's not a good idea.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047/140734). Or are you *really* not after orders that don't occur in the first 9 seconds of each day? If so, you're likely better off adding a `time` value to your table as a computed (and indexed) column.

Comment: Side note, as well, don't use single quotes for aliases, they're for literal strings. Stick to the dialect's delimit identifier, brackets (`[]`) in T-SQL, or the ANSI delimit identifiers, double quotes (`"`). Using syntax like that *can* lead people to do things like `SELECT SomeID AS 'ID' FROM dbo.SomeTable ORDER BY 'ID'` and that *won't* order the data by the column aliased using `'ID'`.

Comment: @Larnu thank you for your note that is the error 80  I try to select the time within 24 hours by mistake I changed it , its solved the issue and working now thank you so much some time when there is big load in work you miss and did some changes not correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lamu the issue with the seconds by mistake changed to 80 and now I changed it to 59 and its working when casting 80 more than 60 seconds and cannot convert it .

I'm try to select the orders time within 24 hours

```
SELECT
      [Order_Payments].[order_id] as 'Order No.'
      , try_convert(numeric(38,2),order_vat) as 'VAT value'
      , try_convert(numeric(38,2),vat_orders.[total_amount]) as 'Total After VAT'
      , [Order_Payments].cash as 'Cash'
      , Order_Payments.mada as 'Mada'
      , Order_Payments.visa as 'Visa'
      , vat_orders.order_date AS 'Order Date'
      , cast(vat_orders.order_date as time) as [time]
      , Customers.CustName as 'Clinic'
      , patients.patient_name as 'Patient Name'       
  FROM [Order_Payments]
  INNER JOIN vat_orders ON [Order_Payments].order_id = vat_orders.ORDER_ID
  INNER JOIN Customers ON [Order_Payments].custid = Customers.CustId
  INNER JOIN Patients ON [Order_Payments].patient_no = patients.patient_no
  WHERE CAST(vat_orders.order_date AS time) BETWEEN '00:00:01' AND '23:59:59'
  AND CAST(vat_orders.order_date AS date) BETWEEN '2021-05-01' AND '2021-05-05'
  AND order_payments.custid = 271
  ORDER BY Order_Payments.custid, Order_Payments.order_id
```

Comment: What about time `00:00:00`?

Comment: @DaleK I used from 00:00:01 instead of 00:00:00 also can start from 00:00:00 thank you.

Comment: @Larnu's comment suggests a better approach just comparing dates and ignoring times. As an aside you should be very careful that you understand how `between` works as its not always logical.

Comment: @DaleK actually I faced errors in some computers when installed the system SELECT between 2 dates not working direct and I have to change the language of the computer from Arabic regions to English United states language then the system and SELECT start working , is this from the CAST ? C# system.

Comment: @ZiadAdnan Most likely that problem comes from the method you use to generate the query in your application. And another good guess is that you don't parameterize your queries - rather you build a query by concatenating what should be parameters (your dates and times and customer ID) into your SELECT statement string.

Comment: The best way to compare dates is to use a half open interval `>= AND <` like so `WHERE vat_orders.order_date >= '20210501' AND vat_orders.order_date < '20210506'`

Comment: @SMor can you give me example please for your idea and how to concatenating and not using the parameters because the system structure and design using stored procedures and parameters then call it from the application .